# twitter-bootstrap - navbar element sometimes pushed under navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, optimization, twitter-bootstrap-3

I customized the default bootstrap navbar to have a image logo, a brand name and a tagline.
All this should sit inline within the right of the navbar.

My code works **BUT sometimes the tagline falls outside of the navbar, under the logo image. Refreshing the page fixes it.**

I was thinking it could be because the page calls too many assets on the first time it loads. Which could explain why refreshing the page fixes it (cached assets).
Would that make sense? How could I fix this?

**NOTE:** This issue is hard to replicate, so I included a drawing of the issue, and excerpts of my code that I hope are useful. 
[image: Issue Drawing]

**HTML (partial):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#home"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">BRAND</a>
        <a class="navbar-tagline" href="#">Aspire for more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
<html>
```

**CSS (partial):**

```
.navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: visible !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.navbar-tagline {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'GibsonLightRegular';
  color: #9f7ab5;
}
```

Thank you for your help! *Let me know if you need more infos.*

Answer (score 0):

Just place this CSS. Hope this will be ok..

```
.navbar-header a{float:left}
```

**Update**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="fav.png"></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

You can add CSS by the class .logo

```
<style>
    .logo{height:50px}
    .logo img{background-color:#889;;height:50px}
</style>
```

Just resize the logo to fit it.

**Screen Shoot of my nav**

[image]

Comment: That was expected. You have changes too many part of BS even broke some rules. See my updates

Comment: Thank you for the help. A few things though: I think you forgot to include the `.logo` class you mention in your HTML. Also it doesn't accurately answer my question because I don't want collapsable links, nor toggle button in my navbar.